# Are request headers necessary with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I'm new to the whole javascript/jquery/ajax scene.  I have a website that I have developed on my personal machine using the following jquery ajax script. It works perfectly on my machine, but then when I upload it to the server, nothing happens.

```
        $.post(
            "action URL here",
            {
                lat_max: params.lat_max,
                lat_min: params.lat_min,
                lng_max: params.lng_max,
                lng_min: params.lng_min,
                building_residents: params.building_residents,
                building_type: params.building_type
            },
            function(json) {
                buildings = json;
                updateMarkers();
                if(polygons.length > 0){
                    for(var i = 0; i < poly_buildings.length; i++){
                        buildPolyBuildings();
                    }
                }else{
                    showAllMarkers();
                }

                filterResults();
            },
            "json"
        );
```

I have been beating my head on this for a couple hours now, and the only idea I have left deals with something I don't understand - request/response headers. When I run this script on my live site, there is nothing under the request/response headers section in Firebug. However, there is lots of stuff there when I run it locally. What am I not getting?

---

There was a request to see the difference in the headers. Here's what I get on my development server:

```
ResponseHeaders 
Date                Tue, 20 Dec 2011 20:45:07 GMT 
X-Powered-By        PHP/5.3.6 
Transfer-Encoding   chunked 
Connection          Keep-Alive
Server              Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6
Content-Type        text/html
Keep-Alive          timeout=5, max=100

RequestHeaders
Content-Type        application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept              application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

---

And here's what I get on the live server:

```
ResponseHeaders
RequestHeaders
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept          application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

Again - I don't know that this is the problem, but it's the only functional difference I can see between the two environments.

Comment: What is the action URL? Because that's quite important to know as you can't send ajax requests to different domains as part of the same origin policy.

Comment: Maybe you should use curl (with the -d and -i options) to post data to your server, and directly check whether the query itself actually works. And append the results to your question once you're done :)

Comment: `buildings = json;` should be `var buildings = jQuery.parseJSON(json);`

Comment: polygons is not defined
maybe json.polygons? show your json format out plz

Comment: what are the lots of stuff? what you expect to see? what you see actually? Normally any ajax request is sent along with `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header.  But its not required.

Comment: @Dunhamzz - I hid the URL because I'm not to publicize the domain yet. However, I appreciate the tip - and it does point to a file within the same domain.

Comment: A cross-domain issue was my first thought as well, problem description sounds spot on. But if it's not: **watch the logs on the server for *any* requests coming in**. Even with cross-domain requests, you'll be getting an OPTIONS pre-flight request. If you're getting proper (HEAD/GET/PUT/POST) requests, look for problems server side. (Error log is key here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. It turns out that the domain I was going to didn't have "www" in front of it - I was going to the naked domain. And the url that it's referenceing in the code has the "www" subdomain in front of it. It solved everything. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using relative URLs has its perks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the error logs on the new server? I recently ran into a problem similar to yours and it turned out that the php on the new server was configured differently than the version on the old server, meaning the page I was hitting via AJAX was failing (and not sending a response back). That could be causing your issue as well.

Comment: Well, I'd totally dive into that a bit further, but I have another site that's running off the same server and uses a script really similar to this one for AJAX requests, and it's working fine. I'm wondering what some possible reasons might be that the headers are empty like that are...? I'm totally baffled.